# Unlocking resource upon Eloqua form completed

Tags: reactjs, eloqua

We have a web app written in React that offers some calculation based on simple sliders.
Now we only want to offer the user a PDF download when the user successfully completed our **Eloqua** form.
If the form is not submitted the PDF show be hidden.

Is that doable?
If yes how?

Answer (score 0):

Use a condition on the **Redirect to Web Page** processing step. If you receive a successful value, create a step to redirect them to the PDF. If not, create another step to redirect them to another landing page. The condition can either be a value passed by your app to a hidden field, and use that hidden field to determine if they meet the criteria. Or, check that all the fields you need are completed before redirecting them to the pdf (x is not null, y is not null, etc).

Or you could apply validation to the individual fields on the Eloqua side or in your react app.